# What is the best way to read from existing Elasticsearch instances in Pyspark preventing mapping/parsing errors?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I have a lot of Elasticsearch indices with many fields that I want to use in Spark. As those indices don't have any mapping specified, using the data gets multiple parsing errors. What is the best way to connect to Elasticsearch preventing any mapping/parsing errors?

I already tried parsing multiple columns as arrays, but that doesn't work as there are lots of nested data.

Some of the errors look strange. I have no idea, for example, why Spark can't parse a timestamp value as string.

In my scenario, I have lots of Elasticsearch instances; I can't change them myself. Moreover, it's impossible to create mappings for each data source manually because there are way too many fields.

Is it maybe an option to use esRDD instead of `spark.read.format()`?

I don't really have code to share because it's a problem with almost all Elasticsearch instances.

I would love to know how I can connect to existing Elasticsearch databases without needing to spend hours debugging the mapping/parsing problems.

Comment: Not sure about the older versions, however, in recent versions, Elasticsearch assumes default mappings for all fields from data. You should be able to see the mappings at these URLs with an HTTP GET: `http://es.address:port/your_index_name/_mapping?pretty=true` (for the specific index: _your_index_name_) and `http://es.address:port/_mapping?pretty=true` (for all mappings within an ES instance.)

Comment: Are you trying to parse the JSON data returned by Elasticsearch? And are you dealing with only one index (only one mapping) or aggregating multiple indices? Also sharing your parsing code (no matter how it looks like) would really help.